# The method 'getContacts' isn't defined for the type 'Type'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm new to the GetX framework and am trying the call the controller class function from the view using the Elevated button but it causes an error.

> The method 'getContacts' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

this is my contoller class

```
  class ContactController extends GetxController {
  var id;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = preferences.getString('id');
    print(id);
  }

  getContact() async {
    // SERVER API URL

    Uri url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/get-contacts');

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'sender': id};

    //json encode
    String? body = json.encode(data);

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: body);

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var contact = jsonDecode(response.body);

    // If Web call Success than Hide the CircularProgressIndicator.
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(contact);
    } else {
      print("error");
    }
  }
}
```

this is my view class

```
class Contacts extends StatefulWidget {
  const Contacts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Contacts> createState() => _ContactsState();
}

class _ContactsState extends State<Contacts> {
  final contactController = Get.put((ContactController));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed:()=>contactController.getContacts(),
            
            child: Text("GET CONTACT")));
  }
}
```

I can't able to call the function inside the elevated Button

```
onPressed:()=>contactController.getContacts(),
```

any one help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it

```
final contactController = Get.put(ContactController());
```